# Compare string date in mongoose with Date.now() or new Date()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a string date saved in MongoDB as such: '19 Dec 2019'. I want to get all the matching date with new Date() i.e current date.

Mongo stored Date:

> db_date: '18 Dec 2019'

. Match this date with current date,we get this using

> current_date: new Date();

and return an array of matches.

```
Model.find() ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        /** converting month from string to num :: Dec to 12 & extracting date & year from string */
        month: {
            $indexOfArray: [[, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Aprl", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
                , { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ['$db_date', " "] }, 1] }]
        }
        , date: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ['$db_date', " "] }, 0] } }, year: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ['$db_date', " "] }, 2] } }
    }
}, {
    /** db_date is being converted to format ISODate() from parts year + month + day & then to this : "2019-12-18" */
    $addFields: {
        db_date: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: {
                    $dateFromParts: {
                        'year': '$year', 'month': '$month', 'day': '$date'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $project: { 'month': 0, 'year': 0, 'date': 0 } },
{
    /** Here we're converting ISODate() from input to like this : "2019-12-19", This is what you actually asked for */
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $eq: ['$db_date', {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: new Date()
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
])
```

This query should help you to get required results, but in my opinion it's a hefty task to do this kind of conversions, You can usually overcome this by thinking thru your transactions at the time of DB design & then by storing data in DB as per your read requirements, if not - in the other way maybe ease your DB by converting the input in your code to match with data stored in DB !!

Comment: Also not sure what exactly you wanted because `new Date()` will give you something like `ISODate("2019-12-19T22:49:11.502Z")` with proper date in time, even though we convert `'18 Dec 2019'` into `ISODate()` - comparing these two would not get you anything as time doesn't match though date does, So we're converting input request to `2019-12-19` && also stored field value to `2019-12-19`, that way all the docs for a given date are matched !!